# Как запускать и останавливать анимацию сss через js?

Tags: javascript, css

у меня есть два css класса

anim-1 & anim-2 внутри них такой код

```
animation: animate-1 1s linear
```

через функцию

```
makeAnim() {

   eye.classList.add("anim-1");

}
```

в js я анимирую елемент в html.

Проблема в том, что анимация проигрывается при вызове функции только один раз, когда вешаю функцию на онклик например. если поставить infinite то одна анимация накладывается на другую.

вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при вызове одной функции запускалась анимация каждый раз по новой без перезагрузки страницы, а предыдущая анимация прерывалась, либо чтобы одна анимация ждала завершения другой. спасибо.

Comment: А как вы добавляете `infinite`? И добавьте ваш код, там особо не ясно какие анимации, как и когда работают.

Comment: animation: some-anim 1s infinite

Comment: кода очень много. но это значение не имеет. мне нужно чтоб любая анимация @keyframes по клику на елемент отрабатывала столько раз, сколько будет нажато на елемент например. function pro1() {

  meat.classList.add("meat-1");

Comment: .meat-1 {
  animation: box-anima-1 1s linear; 
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

Comment: @keyframes box-anima-1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(65deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
}

Comment: при вызове функции 1 раз отработало, потом все не реагирует. если  написать инфините то просто бесконечно проигрывается, мне нужно чтоб именно 1 клик - 1 анимация. буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Начал писать ответ, отвлёкся, а когда вернулся, вы уже и сами нашли решение, которое я хотел предложить)

Comment: А зачем вся эта муть, просто добавьте `1` в конце пропорции анимации и будет вам счастье, что получилось примерно так: `animation: box-anima-1 1s linear 1;`

Answer (score 1):

нашел событие .addEventListener("animationend", () => {

}
)

которое позволяет отследить окончание анимации и убрать класс анимации с елемента

а еще можно сделать classList.toggle

Answer (score 1):

Запускают и останавливают анимацию с помощью CSS-свойства **animation-play-state: running** или **paused** соответственно:

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: progress 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes progress{
    from{transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to{transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id=div>я вращаюсь</div>
<button onclick='div.style="animation-play-state: running"'> старт </button>
<button onclick='div.style="animation-play-state: paused"'> стоп </button>
```

Или второй вариант с таким кодом кнопок:

```html
<button onclick='div.style.animation="progress 10s linear infinite"'> старт </button>
<button onclick='div.style.animation="progress 10s linear infinite paused"'> стоп </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример цикличного изменения анимации (Используя `animationend`):

```js
window.currentAnim = 0

d.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
  window.currentAnim = window.currentAnim+1 > 2 ? 0 : window.currentAnim+1
  d.style.animationName = 'ani'+window.currentAnim
})

d.style.animationName = 'ani'+window.currentAnim
```

```css
#d {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: 1.66s 0s 1 linear both normal running;
}

@keyframes ani0 {
  50% {
    background: red;
  }
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
  50% {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: не в моем случае. я проигрываю анимацию, когда приходят запросы с сервера. я не знаю сколько их будет и когда нужно будет отобразить анимацию. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @АртемWEB В следующий раз, пожалуйста, уточняйте детали, прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: так вы просто внимательнее читайте вопрос, я изначально написал, что нужно проигрывать анимацию по вызову функции, а будет ли вызываться функция после того, как с сервера придет ответ или по клику значение не имеет.

Comment: @АртемWEB Аааа, теперь понял...